# Equation of the plane passing through the three points

Tags: output-formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to put terms in lexicographic order?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9483/how-to-put-terms-in-lexicographic-order)

I write the equation of the plane passing through the three points $A(-1, 5, -2)$, $B(2, 4, -3)$ and $F(4, -8, 6)$, and this is my code

```
A := {-1, 5, -2};
B := {2, 4, -3};
F := {4, -8, 6};
M := {x, y, z};
u := A - B;
v := A - F;
w := A - M;
n := u\[Cross]v;
Sort[Simplify[w.n] == 0]
```

I want the equation $ABF$ has the form

$21 x + 29 y + 34 z-56=0$,

but Mathematica out

$0 == -56 + 21 x + 29 y + 34 z$

What  must I do? Please help me.

Comment: Try `PolynomialForm[Simplify[w.n], TraditionalOrder -> True]`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It really does not matter how to write these equation - the order does not influence mathematical statement. Your both cases are correct mathematically. Notation/style is a different matter. Use transition to traditional notation:

```
TraditionalForm[Simplify[w.n] == 0]
```

[image]

To get a better grip on the subject please read [**Polynomial Orderings**](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/PolynomialOrderings.html).

Comment: Also, perhaps a warning is in order: tweaking expressions to have Mathematica write them the way you like is many times very difficult. Avoid trying it until you get a good grip.

Comment: @belisarius good point. I add a tutorial link.