# How can I reorder the factors in the terms of a polynomial?

Tags: formatting, polynomials, order

How can I reorder the factors in the terms of a polynomial? Consider

```
poly1 = \!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(1\), \(3\)] + \*SubsuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(2\), \(3\)] + \*SubsuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(3\), \(3\)]\  - \ \(TraditionalForm\`\*SuperscriptBox[SubscriptBox[\(σ\), \(1\)], \(3\)]\)\) /.    Subscript[σ,     1] -> (Subscript[x, 1] + Subscript[x, 2] + Subscript[x, 3]) //   Expand
```

$$\begin{align*}-3 x_2 x_1^2-3 x_3 x_1^2-3 x_2^2 x_1-3 x_3^2 x_1-6 x_2 x_3 x_1-3 x_2 x_3^2-3 x_2^2 x_3\tag{1}\end{align*}$$

```
MonomialList[poly1, {Subscript[x, 1], Subscript[x, 2], Subscript[x,   3]}, "Lexicographic"]
```

$$\begin{align*}\left\{-3 x_1^2 x_2,-3 x_1^2 x_3,-3 x_1 x_2^2,-6 x_1 x_2 x_3,-3 x_1 x_3^2,-3 x_2^2 x_3,-3 x_2 x_3^2\right\}\tag{2}\end{align*}$$

```
% /. List -> Plus
```

$$\begin{align*}-3 x_2 x_1^2-3 x_3 x_1^2-3 x_2^2 x_1-3 x_3^2 x_1-6 x_2 x_3 x_1-3 x_2 x_3^2-3 x_2^2 x_3\tag{3}\end{align*}$$

Question1: How can I get

$$\begin{align*}-3 x_1^2 x_2-3 x_1^2 x_3-3 x_1 x_2^2-6 x_1 x_2 x_3-3 x_1 x_3^2-3 x_2^2 x_3-3 x_2 x_3^2\tag{4}\end{align*}$$

Question2: Even better if possible, how can I get

$$\begin{align*}-3\left( x_1^2 x_2+x_2^2x_1+\text{...}\right)-6 x_1 x_2 x_3\tag{5}\end{align*}$$

My goal is to keep the order of the terms in (2) unchanged when I copy (4)/(5) into an inline formula cell.

Comment: Does `Row@MonomialList[..]` work for you, or do want the TeX output?  I'm not sure I'm understanding the question correctly.

Comment: @MichaelE2 haha, yes, question1 just can be solved by `Row@%`, and the result can be copied to an `InlineFormula` Cell.

Comment: Actually `Row` works in this case because of the negative coefficients.  For positive coefficients, you'd have to insert a "+".

Comment: There is the undocumented `PolynomialForm`, but it doesn't seem to work quite right (see [9483](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9483/how-to-put-terms-in-lexicographic-order), [15744](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15744/how-to-keep-collect-result-in-order), [etc.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=PolynomialForm)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Question 1

As I said in a comment,

```
Row@MonomialList[poly1,
      {Subscript[x, 1], Subscript[x, 2], Subscript[x, 3]}, "Lexicographic"]
```

---

However, it works easily here because all the coefficients are negative.  The following `polyForm` handles level 1 terms (ignores nesting).  It formats the polynomial `f` with the monomials in a specified `order`.  It will expand a polynomial `f` (via `MonomialList`), unless an explicit list of `terms` is given.  It takes the same arguments as `MonomialList` in the case where the polynomial is passed.  If the `terms` are passed directly in a list, they will be formatted in the same order as they occur in the list.

```
polyForm[f_Plus, vars_: Automatic, order_: "Lexicographic"] := 
  polyForm[MonomialList[f, vars /. Automatic :> Variables[f], order]];
polyForm[terms_List] := Module[{signs},
   signs = 
    First[Cases[#, c_?NumericQ :> Sign[c]] /. {} -> {1}] & /@ 
     Rest@terms;
   PrecedenceForm[Row[Riffle[{1}~Join~signs terms,
      signs /. {1 -> "\[MediumSpace]+\[MediumSpace]", -1 -> 
         "\[MediumSpace]-\[MediumSpace]"}]], 10]
   ];

polyForm[x_, ___] := x; (* leave other stuff alone *)
```

#### Question 2

In this case you can gather the terms by the number of variables each contains:

```
Total[Factor /@ Plus @@@ GatherBy[List @@ poly1, Length@Variables[#] &]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or you can use `Row` to keep them in the desired order (as in the question):

```
Row[Factor /@ Plus @@@ GatherBy[List @@ poly1, Length@Variables[#] &]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or use `polyForm`, which will yield the standard spacing around the last minus sign:

```
polyForm[Factor /@ Plus @@@ GatherBy[List @@ poly1, Length@Variables[#] &]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

Mr.Wizard pointed out that my order is not the same as the desired order in the OP, something I overlooked.  Here is a fix:

```
Factor /@ Plus @@@ GatherBy[MonomialList[poly1, Variables[poly1], "Lexicographic"], 
     Length@Variables[#] &] /. poly_Plus :> polyForm[poly] // polyForm
```

Here is another:

```
MapAll[# /. poly_Plus :> polyForm[poly] &, 
 Total[Factor /@ Plus @@@ GatherBy[MonomialList[poly1, Variables[poly1], "Lexicographic"], 
     Length @ Variables[#] &]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For the curious, I'll share the following.  Using `ReplaceAll` with `poly_Plus :> polyForm[poly]` does not work on the `Total` in the preceding example because is it applies the replacement at the top level first and `polyForm` expands the polynomial.  Here is a way around that, but it does reverse the order at the top level:

```
Total[Factor /@ Plus @@@ 
    GatherBy[MonomialList[poly1, Variables[poly1], "Lexicographic"], 
     Length@Variables[#] &]] /. Plus -> (polyForm[List[##]] &)
```

Comment: Michael, I don't think this is quite right yet; for example, shouldn't the term `−3 x1 x3^3` be the *third* from the right, not the *second* as shown above?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Oops, that's right (assuming you mean `-3 x1 x3^2`) - I blithely thought the point was just to separate the kinds of terms.

Comment: Oops.. yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: `polyForm[...]//TeXForm` complains with`TeXForm::unspt: TeXForm of TemplateSlotSequence[1,] is not supported.`.  Is it possible to change `polyForm` so that the output can be given to `TeXForm`?

Comment: @Hotschke This works on the OP's example: `RowBox@First@MakeBoxes[#, StandardForm] &@
    First@polyForm[
      Factor /@ 
       Plus @@@ GatherBy[List @@ poly1, Length@Variables[#] &]] /. 
   "\"\[MediumSpace]-\[MediumSpace]\"" -> "-" // RawBoxes // TeXForm` -- Might also need the substitution `"\[MediumSpace]+\[MediumSpace]" -> "+"`, but it doesn't come up in this case.

Comment: Actually, I think if the `\[MediumSpace]` instances are deleted from the def. of `polyForm`, no substitution rules are needed.

Answer (score 3):

Related questions:

- [Displaying a series obtained by evaluating a Taylor series](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6358/121)
- [How to keep Collect[] result in order?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15744/121)
- [How do I get a two-term polynomial with a leading negative sign to display in the correct (i.e. textbook) order?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20714/121)

As shown in answer to the third question above you could use:

```
HoldForm[+##] & @@ MonomialList[poly1]
```

[image]

(`+##` is shorthand for `Plus[##]`)

As already noted above and in that answer [`Row`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Row.html) is not sufficient as it will not handle the signs of terms correctly.

For the second question I am borrowing part of Michael's answer, but my result is different and I believe correct:

```
format = HoldForm[+##] & @@ MonomialList@ # &;

Factor /@ Plus @@@ GatherBy[List @@ poly1, Length@Variables[#] &];

Plus @@ MapAt[format, %, {1, 2}]
```

[image]

The order of these terms appears to match your requested output whereas Michael's output does not.

Comment: Interesting___, `HoldForm[+##]`

Comment: @HyperGroups  I fixed mine, but I must admit Mr.Wizard's is much more elegant!

Answer (score 1):

This can easily be done by straight manipulation with the Presentations Application, which I sell.

```
<< Presentations` 

step1 = poly1 // MapLevelParts[FactorOut[-3], {{1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7}}] 
step2 = MapAt[HoldOrderForm[{1, 3, 2, 5, 4, 6}], step1, {{2, 2}}]
```

[image]
[image]

FactorOut will factor an arbitrary expression out of an existing expression - even if it is not initially in the expression. MapLevelParts will map a function to a set of level parts in an expression (usually a sum or product or sometimes a list). It applies as a whole to the sub sum, product or list. In your example the level parts are at level 1 but it is also possible to specify a set of level parts at a deeper position.

Comment: This also doesn't seem to match the requested order.  Compare your result to mine.

Comment: @ Mr. Wizard. Well that is easy to fix with another Presentations routine, HoldOrderForm, which allows the permutation of terms or factors. However, the first form does have the advantage of being a normal non-held Mathematica expression.