# The ordering problem of multivariate polynomials

Tags: output-formatting, formatting, polynomials

This is the result of Taylor expansion of a binary function

```
F[k_] := Sum[Binomial[k, r]*Δx^r*Δy^(k - r)*   Derivative[r, k - r][f][x0, y0], {r, 0, k}]
f[x_, y_] := x^2*y^2
Expand[Sum[F[i]/i!, {i, 0, 3}]]
```

$$F[\text{k$\_$}]\text{:=}\sum _{r=0}^k \text{$\Delta $x}^r \binom{k}{r} \text{$\Delta $y}^{k-r} f^{(r,k-r)}[\text{x0},\text{y0}]$$
$$f[\text{x$\_$},\text{y$\_$}]\text{:=}x^2 y^2$$
$$\text{Expand}\left[\sum _{i=0}^3 \frac{F[i]}{i!}\right]$$
The output is not ordered by the sum of the powers of $\Delta x$ and $\Delta y$ 
[image]
But I want to sort this polynomials by power order of $\Delta x$ and $\Delta y$ like this:
[image]
How can I do this with functions like `Collect` or `Simplify`?

Comment: You are aware `Plus[]` is `Orderless`, yes?

Comment: Is this related https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30216/how-can-i-reorder-the-factors-in-the-terms-of-a-polynomial?

Comment: @J.M. Yes, I don't want the sorting of the results to be broken by the unordered properties of the `Plus` function and I want to arrange the results as required.

Comment: @PleaseCorrectGrammarMistakes Do you want this for the output or you just want to read the resulting prefactors easily?

Comment: @A_user_with_NoName I want to read the resulting prefactors easily.I want to write a custom function to sort the output results according to the above requirements.

Comment: @PleaseCorrectGrammarMistakes in order for you to be able to read the prefactors easily, I suggest that you use CoefficientlList. If you are interested in reading just one prefactor quickly, then you can use Coefficient. For the custom function, I have not been able to bring it in the form that you want. The link that I posted gives similar -ish result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
orderedForm[poly_, var_List] := 
  HoldForm[+##] & @@ 
   MonomialList[poly, 
     var][[Ordering[-Total[#] & @@@ CoefficientRules[poly, var], All, 
      GreaterEqual]]];
orderedForm[
 Expand[Sum[
   F[i]/i!, {i, 0, 3}]], {Δx, Δy}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, Wolfram Cloud seems to give an almost-desired answer, clearly indicating use of a differing subroutine. Posting this an an answer as it is too much for a comment:

```
F[k_] := Sum[Binomial[k, r]*\[CapitalDelta]x^r*\[CapitalDelta]y^(k - r)*   Derivative[r, k - r][f][x0, y0], {r, 0, k}]
f[x_, y_] := x^2*y^2
Expand[Sum[F[i]/i!, {i, 0, 3}]]
```

Gives

```
x0^2*y0^2 + 2*x0*y0^2*\[CapitalDelta]x + y0^2*\[CapitalDelta]x^2 + 2*x0^2*y0*\[CapitalDelta]y + 4*x0*y0*\[CapitalDelta]x*\[CapitalDelta]y + 2*y0*\[CapitalDelta]x^2*\[CapitalDelta]y + x0^2*\[CapitalDelta]y^2 + 2*x0*\[CapitalDelta]x*\[CapitalDelta]y^2
```

[image: Image of the above Wolfram Cloud Input & Ouput]

While close, this does not satisfy the OP’s requirements, although it does provide impetus for further investigation of the dependence of the polynomial ordering displayed.