# How can I convert $(x - 1)^2 + (y + 2)^2 + (z - 5)^2 - 25 = 0$ to $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 2x + 4y - 10z + 5 = 0$?

Tags: output-formatting

With Maple, I tried

```
expand((x - 1)^2 + (y + 2)^2 + (z - 5)^2 - 25 = 0);
```

and got

[image]

With Mathematica, I tried

```
Expand[(x - 1)^2 + (y + 2)^2 + (z - 5)^2 - 25 == 0]
```

I got

> 5 - 2 x + x^2 + 4 y + y^2 - 10 z + z^2 == 0

How can I get the result like result of Maple?

Comment: Related: [33130](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33130/why-does-mathematica-order-polynomial-forms-in-reverse-from-traditional-order/33133#33133)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
HoldForm[+##] & @@ 
 MonomialList[(x - 1)^2 + (y + 2)^2 + (z - 5)^2 - 25, 
  "DegreeLexicographic"]
```

---

$x^2+y^2+z^2-2 x+4 y-10 z+5$

Answer (score 2):

cheating by using answer in [The ordering problem of multivariate polynomials](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/213723/the-ordering-problem-of-multivariate-polynomials)

With very minor change to make the order reverses from the original code.

```
p = Expand[(x - 1)^2 + (y + 2)^2 + (z - 5)^2 - 25];
orderedForm[poly_, var_List] := 
  HoldForm[+##] & @@ 
   MonomialList[poly, 
     var][[Ordering[Total[#] & @@@ CoefficientRules[poly, var], All, 
      GreaterEqual]]];
orderedForm[p, {x, y, z}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

There should be simpler way I would think.

Answer (score 1):

While it doesn't give exactly the form you request, you can get an order that you might prefer, using `TraditionalForm`

```
Expand[(x - 1)^2 + (y + 2)^2 + (z - 5)^2 - 25 == 0] // TraditionalForm
(* x^2-2 x+y^2+4 y+z^2-10 z+5==0 *)
```