# How to write a^2 - a b + b^2 - a c - b c + c^2 has the form a^2 + b^2 + c^2 - a b - b c - c a?

Tags: output-formatting, polynomials, sorting

I tried

```
expr = a^2 - a  b + b^2 - a  c - b  c + c^2;

HoldForm[+##]&@@MonomialList[expr,#]& /@ {
"Lexicographic","DegreeLexicographic",
"DegreeReverseLexicographic","NegativeLexicographic","NegativeDegreeLexicographic",
"NegativeDegreeReverseLexicographic"
} // Column
```

and [The ordering problem of multivariate polynomials](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/213723/the-ordering-problem-of-multivariate-polynomials).

Neither not get the expected result.   How can I get the result $a^2+b^2+c^2-a b-b c-c a$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
expr = a^2 - a b + b^2 - a c - b c + c^2;
HoldForm[+##] & @@ 
 ReverseSortBy[
  MonomialList[expr], {Total@Exponent[#, Variables[expr]] &, 
   Max@Exponent[#, Variables[expr]] &}]
```

---

$a^2+b^2+c^2-a b-a c-b c$

The same code in a shorter form:

```
expr = a^2 - a b + b^2 - a c - b c + c^2;
HoldForm[+##] & @@ 
 ReverseSortBy[
  MonomialList[
   expr], #@*(Exponent[#, Variables[expr]] &) & /@ {Total, Max}]
```