# How to invert the default order of polynomial?

Tags: polynomials

By default, Mathematica outputs polynomials starting with smallest degree.

How can I invert this?

Comment: You could use [`TraditionalForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TraditionalForm.html) for this.

Comment: @m0nhawk  sorry but I do not want other consequences of TraditionalForm here.

Comment: So, can you share more about the use case.

Comment: Something like `TraditionalForm[a x^3 + b x^4 + c, ParameterVariables -> {a, b, c}]`? See also [tutorial/PolynomialOrderings](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/PolynomialOrderings.html).

Comment: @kguler traditional form does not fit here. After Traditional Form I cannot copy to Latex, for instance.

Comment: @Anixx, wrap everything in `TeXForm` to get an output that can be copy/pasted into Latex: e.g., copying the output  of `TraditionalForm[a x^3 + b x^4 + c, 
  ParameterVariables -> {a, b, c}] // TeXForm`  and pasting here (between `$` signs) gives $b x^4+a x^3+c$

Comment: @kguler there can be many parameters (as many as the degree of the polynomia)l. It is easier to re-type all manually than list the parameters in this option.

Comment: Anixx, maybe using `DeleteCases` on `Variables`, .e.g.  `expr = a x^3 + b x^4 + c; TeXForm[ TraditionalForm[expr, DeleteCases[Variables[expr], x]]]`?

Comment: Is [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9483/how-to-put-terms-in-lexicographic-order) what you're looking for?

Comment: @Oleksandr R. maybe, actually! Need more look at it.