# How to order a polynomial in descending powers of x?

Tags: symbolic, polynomials

This should be very simple, even silly
If I ask this mathematica

```
 Expand [(x + 1) (x + 2) (x + 3)]
```

Mathematica delivers me well

```
 6 + 11 x + 6 x ^ 2 + x ^ 3
```

as achieving this result

```
x ^ 3 + 6 x 2 + 11 x +6
```

Comment: `Plus[ ]` is `Orderless` ...

Comment: `expr = (x + 1) (x + 2) (x + 3); expr // Expand // TraditionalForm`

Comment: Related: [(6358)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6358/121), [(9483)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9483/121), [(9570)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9570/121), [(15744)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15744/121), [(20714)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20714/121), [(30216)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30216/121)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works nicely:

```
PolynomialForm[(x + 1) (x + 2) (x + 3) // Expand, TraditionalOrder -> True]
   x^3 + 6 x^2 + 11 x + 6
```

The problem with `PolynomialForm[]` is that it is merely a wrapper, like `MatrixForm[]` for matrices. So, this makes things display pretty, but it should not be given as input for further calculations. You can copy the output, however.

Comment: thanks , what order I put the letter out for more big and bold?