# problem with Collect when using indexed variables

Tags: algebraic-manipulation

I'm not getting the expected output when I use `Collect` with indexed variables.

```
mA = Array[a[##] &, {2, 2}]
Collect[CharacteristicPolynomial[mA, t], t]
```

produces

```
{{a[1, 1], a[1, 2]}, {a[2, 1], a[2, 2]}}
t^2 - a[1, 2] a[2, 1] + t (-a[1, 1] - a[2, 2]) + a[1, 1] a[2, 2]
```

Note that although I've tried to collect terms in `t`, constant terms have not been collected.
Explanation?

Mma has a standard order when it collects powers.  This order is not being honored.  It is also standard for Mma to collect terms in `t^0` (since I am collecting in `t` in this example).  This also is not being honored.  I realize the coefficients in this example are not symbols.  My question is simple: why should this matter when I am collecting in `t`?

Contrast with this second example, which does give the expected output:

```
mA = {{a11, a12}, {a21, a22}}
Collect[CharacteristicPolynomial[mA, t], t]
```

produces

```
{{a11, a12}, {a21, a22}}
-a12 a21 + a11 a22 + (-a11 - a22) t + t^2
```

Note the standard ordering in the variable `t` in the second example.

Comment: It does : `Collect[CharacteristicPolynomial[mA, t], t, h]`

Comment: What would be your expected output?

Comment: @MarcoB I've edited the question to be clear about the expected output.  I think belisarius may be suggesting my expectation is wrong, but I need more of a hint. Thanks.

Comment: In your last example you show the standard ordering of the variables you want to see. But _Mathematica_ doesn't see expressions of the form `a[i_, j_]` as variables because they are not atoms. So standard ordering of variables does not apply.

Comment: @m_goldberg But ... I'm asking to collect in `t`.  So why does that matter?  (Clearly it does, but I'm missing something.)

Comment: You got collection  over powers of `t`. What you are complaining about is how t-free terms are ordered. All I can say is that `a[1, 2]` looks very different than `a12` to _Mathematica_. Use `FullForm` to examine the results of your to examples of collecting terms to see how different the internal forms are.

Comment: @m_goldberg  Mma has a standard order when it collects powers.  This order is not being honored.  It is also standard for Mma to collect terms in t^0 (in this example).  This also is not being honored.  Sure I realized the coefficients are not symbols.  My question is simple: why should this matter when I am collecting in `t`?

Comment: Note that directly entering `-a[1, 2] a[2, 1] + a[1, 1] a[2, 2] + t (-a[1, 1] - a[2, 2]) + t^2` will give you the scrambled-looking output you have. Consider this: `SetAttributes[f, Orderless]; f @@ {-a[1, 2] a[2, 1], a[1, 1] a[2, 2], t (-a[1, 1] - a[2, 2]), t^2}`.

Comment: Try this: `cp = CharacteristicPolynomial[mA, t]
Collect[cp - (cp /. t -> 0), {t, t^2}] + (Evaluate[(cp /. t -> 0)] // 
   HoldForm)  ` . Have fun!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of a couple of ways to interpret this question.

If the problem is getting the coefficients, use [`CoefficientList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CoefficientList.html) or [`CoefficientArrays`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CoefficientArrays.html):

```
mA = Array[a[##] &, {2, 2}];
CoefficientList[CharacteristicPolynomial[mA, t], t]
(*  {-a[1, 2] a[2, 1] + a[1, 1] a[2, 2], -a[1, 1] - a[2, 2], 1}  *)
```

If that's not right, maybe it's output formatting.

```
PolynomialForm[Collect[CharacteristicPolynomial[mA, t], t], 
 TraditionalOrder -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

See for instance, [How to put terms in lexicographic order?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9483/how-to-put-terms-in-lexicographic-order/9490#9490), and its linked questions.

Comment: Your second suggestion is interesting and somewhat helpful.  Your first just however just underlines my question:  as I said: I just want to understand why terms in t^0 are not collected together by `Collect`.  I thought that was what `Collect` was supposed to do.  How am I misreading the documentation?

Comment: @Alan I suppose it is because `Plus` is [`Flat`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flat.html) and does not support grouping in the way it is done in school algebra.

Comment: Aha, now that is a good answer!  I am going to accept your answer but it would be best if you could move your comment to the answer.  An implication of this is that when the documentation says that `Collect` "collects together terms involving the same powers of objects matching `x`" that this does not mean it will collect together terms in `x^0`.  Thanks.