# Who can explain the strange behavior of command "Last"

Tags: list-manipulation

### Situation

I use `Last` to extract the last element of an expression. Let `poly=a+b*c+Log[a]+z`.

### Problem

When Using `Last@poly`, I expect the output is `z`. However, the command gave me `Log[a]`.

### Debug

With `FullForm@poly`, I found the output is `Plus[a,Times[b,c],z,Log[a]]`. So, `Log[a]` should be the correct answer of the command, but not my expected answer.

### My Question

The strange behavior confuse me.

1. I wonder whether elements of an `expression` in mathematica have **definite** order.
2. If the answer is "no", is there any alternative other than `Last` to avoid the undetermined behavior, so that I can extract particular element ?

Comment: `Plus[]` is commutative, so it has the `Orderless` attribute, and sorts its arguments into a canonical order. Anyway: `Defer[a + b c + Log[a] + z][[1, -1]]`. Not recommended, though.

Comment: Take a look at the output of `poly = ...`.  The last element is indeed `Log[a]` because Mathematica sorts the terms of `Plus`.  Why?  Check here: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Orderless.html http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FlatAndOrderlessFunctions.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I wonder whether elements of an expression in mathematica have definite order.

Yes, the one you get after evaluating an expression. See [Polynomial Ordering in the Wolfram Documentation Center](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PolynomialOrderings.html). In your case, `poly = a + b*c + Log[a] + z` evaluates to

> a + b c + z + Log[a]

So `Last` does indeed do what it's supposed to.

You could try extracting the elements with patterns (depending on what terms you actually need to extract), or you could use something like `PolynomialForm[%,TraditionalOrder->True]` (found [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9483/how-to-put-terms-in-lexicographic-order)).

**Some general information about term ordering in Mathematica**

Functions in Mathematica can have the [`Orderless`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Orderless.html) attribute, which means that Mathematica will (re)arrange the supplied terms in canonical order, as described in [this tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FlatAndOrderlessFunctions.html). Canonical ordering is used as a standard way to arrange terms in commutative and associative functions (such as `Plus` or `Times` in your case) for purposes of for example pattern matching.

Comment: Can you please also mention `Orderless` and link to the relevant tutorial?

Comment: I added the information, thanks.